# Google wallet android sandbox find transaction records

Tags: android, transactions, sandbox

I follow the example of Google developers!

https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/android/tutorial

In my nexus 7, I can run the whole process, no errors.
I use the sandbox mode.

But I use my buyers and sellers account login account under the two on the site, can not find any record of the transaction.

https://Wallet-web.sandbox.google.com

Wallet-web.sandbox.google.com/merchant

Why?

Comment: Did u find answer for this?

Comment: Sandbox transactions aren't showing up for me either after a fullwallet request success and firing off a notifyTransactionStatusRequest